# How to call multiple objects

Tags: java, oop

I have a class and I have created 10 objects, their names are obj1, obj2, obj3, and so on.

The thing is that I want to access their attributes, for example:

-obj1.name

-obj2.name

-obj3.name

-obj...

Is it possible to get those names in a dynamic way without having to copy-paste that same line over and over? Let's say with a for loop for example. Or is it impossible to do so?

I'm kinda new to the POO world, sorry if it is a dumb question.

I have thought in just doing something like this, but I know it won't work:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
String name = obj(i).name;
System.out.println(name);
}
```

Comment: Use an array, rather than separately declared variables.

Comment: or some collection like `ArrayList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes It's possible:

```
// initiation the array of objects with 10 new objects. Each has a different name.
MyObject[] array_of_objects = new MyObject[10]
for(int i = 0; i < array_of_objects.length; i++){
  array_of_objects[i] = new MyObject("object_name_"+i);
}

// now printing the name property of each object:
for(int i = 0; i < array_of_objects.length; i++){
  System.out.println(array_of_objects[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can't use local vars in "dynamic way". But seems you simply can use array:

```
MyObject[] myObjects = new MyObject[] {myObject1, myObject2, ..., myObject10}
for (MyObject myObject : myObjects) {
   System.out.println(myObject.name); // "name" field must be initalized manually before
}
```

Or in such way:

```
Map<String, MyObject> myObjects = new LinkedHashMap<>();
myObjects.put("somename", myObject1);
...
myObjects.put("othername", myObject10);
for (Map.Entry<String, MyObject> entry : myObjects.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "list":

```
List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();

nameList.add("name1");
nameList.add("name2");
nameList.add("name3");
```

Then do your loop operation:

```
for (String name : nameList) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(nameList.get(i));
}
```

Comment: For "String" in "List<String>", "String" is an object, you can change it into any object you defined.